# discord.py bot - Nuke command not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am having issues with my nuke command which is supposed to delete the current channel and clone it, clearing all the messages. The problem is that it doesn't work **at all** and **doesn't give any errors!**

Code

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue,
        title=f":boom: Channel ({ctx.channel.name}) has been nuked :boom:",
        description=f"Nuked by: {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}"
    )
    nuke_ch = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=ctx.channel.name)
    new_ch = await nuke_ch.clone(reason="Being nuked and remade!")
    await nuke_ch.delete()
    sendem = new_ch.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    sendem.delete()
```

If you have a solution, please answer this question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to also request `nuke_ch` as an argument in your command. You just work with `ctx`, nothing more.

***Here is a `nuke` command that I used to work with:***

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx, channel_name):
    channel_id = int(''.join(i for i in channel_name if i.isdigit()))
    existing_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id) # Get channel ID
    if existing_channel:
        await ctx.send("**This channel will be nuked in X seconds.**")
        await asyncio.sleep(YourValue) # Can be removed
        await existing_channel.delete() # Deletes the old channel
        existing = await existing_channel.clone() # Clones the channel again
        await existing.send("**This channel was nuked/re-created!**") 

    else:
        await ctx.send(f'**No channel named `{channel_name}` was found.**')
```

**What did we do?**

- Get the channel by ID or name
- Check if the channel exists and then nuke it
- Built in an error handler if the channel was not found

Comment: There's no need of this. I got my answer with *just* ctx

Comment: @TigerNinja "If you have a solution" so I gave you mine.